# Passing a method reference as parameter

Tags: java, lambda, method-reference

In a case like this:

```
public class Order {
    List<Double> prices = List.of(1.00, 10.00, 100.00);
    List<Double> pricesWithTax = List.of(1.22, 12.20, 120.00);

    Double sumBy(/* method reference */) {
        Double sum = 0.0;
        for (Double price : /* method reference */) {
            sum += price;
        }
        return sum;
    }

    public List<Double> getPrices() { return prices; }
    public List<Double> getPricesWithTax() { return pricesWithTax; }
}
```

how can I declare the `sumBy` method in a way that can be called like this:

```
Order order = new Order();
var sum = order.sumBy(order::getPrices);
var sumWithTaxes = order.sumBy(order::getPricesWithTax);
```

**I'm not using the Java 8 API for the sum because my goal is only to understand how pass a method reference.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want a [`Supplier`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html) like

```
Double sumBy(Supplier<List<Double>> f) {
    Double sum = 0.0;
    for (Double price : f.get()) {
        sum += price;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Your `List.of` syntax was giving me errors. So I did

```
List<Double> prices = Arrays.asList(1.00, 10.00, 100.00);
List<Double> pricesWithTax = Arrays.asList(1.22, 12.20, 120.00);
```

Then I tested like

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Order order = new Order();
    double sum = order.sumBy(order::getPrices);
    double sumWithTaxes = order.sumBy(order::getPricesWithTax);
    System.out.printf("%.2f %.2f%n", sum, sumWithTaxes);
}
```

Outputs

```
111.00 133.42
```

Comment: `List.of()` is Java 9+. Come on, join the new world, where the current version is Java 15. 

Comment: @Andreas Hadoop stack I'm using is stuck at 8 (for now).

Comment: *FYI:* My Eclipse workspace currently has 8 projects with stub `main` method for writing test code for StackOverflow, one project per Java version from Java 7 to Java 14. Haven't installed Java 15 yet, shame on me. Projects are named `Test07` to `Test14`, with class named the same, which makes it simple to test newer features, or to limit to only older features, as needed. Naming the class the same prevents confusion if more than one of them are open at the same time, which is useful for comparing features/results by Java version.

Comment: You should declare `sum` as `double` instead of `Double`. In other words, instead of unboxing the current value and boxing the next value in every loop iteration, only box the end result.

Answer (score 3):

Your 2 methods take no argument and return an object, so that fits the [`Supplier.get()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html) method.

Don't use `Double` for the `sum` variable, since that will auto-box and auto-unbox way too much.

Method can be `static` since it doesn't use any fields or other methods of the class.

```java
static double sumBy(Supplier<List<Double>> listGetter) {
    double sum = 0.0;
    for (double price : listGetter.get()) {
        sum += price;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Better yet:

```java
static double sumBy(Supplier<List<Double>> listGetter) {
    return listGetter.get().stream().mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue).sum();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the `Supplier<T>` functional interface is what you’re looking for:

```
Double sumBy(Supplier<Collection<Double>> supplier) {
  Collection<Double> prices = supplier.get();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Double sumBy(Supplier<List<Double>> doubles)`